# Figures Assigned Rogue Numbers When Adding \caption

Tags: captions

I've been trying to caption the figures in my paper, like 'Figure 1', 'Figure 2', etc. Instead, something like 'Figure 1.1' is prepended to the caption. Could anyone please explain?

Upd: here's an example:

```
begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=6cm]{wang_fa}
\centering
\caption {Figure 6. Different RF pulses’ effect on tip angle (\emph {flip angle, FA}) calibration. [i8]}
\end{figure}
```

What I get is: 'Figure 2.3. Figure 3...'

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that illustrates your problem. The example should be in such a sate that others can just copy it and test without changing anything. Without such an example, we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Caption should be: `\caption {Different RF pulses’ effect on tip angle (\emph {flip angle, FA}) calibration. [i8]}. For more help  wee need MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Answer (score 1):

Let me spell out my above comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
Figure produced with your code fragment;
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=5.4cm]{example-image-duck}%{wang_fa}{wang_fa}
\centering
\caption {Figure 6. Different RF pulses’ effect on tip angle (\emph {flip angle, FA}) calibration. [i8]}
\end{figure}

Figure produced with proposed correction of your code fragment;
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=5.4cm]{example-image-duck}%{wang_fa}
\caption {Different RF pulses’ effect on tip angle (\emph {flip angle, FA}) calibration. [i8]}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid the paper is too long for me to post it here. The issue occurs within a multi-page document.

Comment: Please send MWE, a small but complete document which reproduce your problem. Unfortunately we can't prepare MWE , this is your task (only you know your document).  MWE can prepare from your document where step by step remove part of document and see if then problem vanish.  It can happen that in this proces you will find source of your problem.

Comment: @AlexM Zarko's answer is an MWE that shows your problem and the answer to it. You could have produced a similar MWE; your multipages have nothing to do with your problem.